# django on windows server 2008

Tags: python, django

Does Django work on Windows server 2008?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does.  Django can run on apache which runs just fine on windows 2008. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways to run it on Windows. You can do it with [Apache](http://wiki.thinkhole.org/howto:django_on_windows), but even better it can be run from IIS using any of the following WSGI compliant extensions:

- [PyISAPIe](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/pyisapie)
- [ISAPI-WSGI](http://code.google.com/p/isapi-wsgi/)

Comment: Actually IIS7 is awesome for FastCGI, so it's not even necessary to use ISAPI. And yes, by far use IIS7 over Apache, it's much better on the Windows platform.